# regex match and group in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Wanted to see if any one can help, I have a following string

```
"Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates where  


|E|. This is a sample string"
```

I want regex expression which will replace any white spaces including extra spaces and new line character before any occurrence of |E|, where "E" can be any number of alphabets surrounded by | and |.

I was thinking some thing along

```
   $s =~ s/\s*</ </ig;
```

but here it will only look at the starting | not the closing "|".

The end result should be like below

"Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates where |E|. This is a sample string"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead `(?= ..)` to match what should be ahead of `\s+` in order to match it.

```
$s =~ s/\s+(?= \|\w+\|)/ /xig;
```

Answer (score 4):

How does one differentiate a start pipe from an end pipe?

Assuming one can't, then the following might help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

$data =~ s{\s+(?=\|)}{ }g;

print $data;

__DATA__
Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates where  


|E|. This is a sample string
```

Outputs:

```
Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates where |E|. This is a sample string
```